# RecyclerView is loading twice product on click event in recyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i have applied recyclerView in fragment in which i am showing product from api that is working fine. i have performed click listener on recyclerView, when i click the product and go to next fragment. But when i go to previous fragment that then my recycelerView loads data again and again. how i can avoid from this. i want to that it loads data once.
here is my code xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lsCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**here is my recyclerView Code:**

```
 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;

 public void getInfo(View view){
    lsCategory =  view.findViewById(R.id.lsCategory);
}
public void setInfo(){
    getData();
}
public void getData(){
    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLs.homeMainURL,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
                //categories
                JSONArray categoryArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ListCategories");
                setCategoryAdapter(categoryArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
private void setCategoryAdapter(JSONArray array) {

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            final String name = object.getString("Name");
            final int Id = object.getInt("ID");
            categories.add(new Category(Id, name));
        }

    }catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, categories);
    lsCategory.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    lsCategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
}
```

**and here is my category Adapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(categories.get(position));
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewItemName;
    private int Id ;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoris);
    }
    public void setData(final Category category){
        textViewItemName.setText(category.getCategoryName());
        Id = category.getId();

        textViewItemName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ExpandableCategoryList fragment = new ExpandableCategoryList();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("Id",Id);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ((MainActivity)context).replaceFragment(fragment,
                        "TAG",null,false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can be add previous fragment change code?

Comment: show your full fragment code where recycle view code is !

Comment: kindly can you explain it

Comment: Setting `Adapter` inside for loop might help maybe? And after that, `adapter.notifydatachange();` Also, `add(new Category(Id, name));` might create another item too. Which is suspicious.

Comment: show full fragment code. you have share recycle view code. Show all code of the fragment where recycle view is loading data.

Comment: now see my full code

Comment: also i have applied adapter.notifydatachange(); but nothing changed

Comment: That's fine, please clear 2 things. 1)-how you going back to previous fragment ? either by pressing back button or by replacing fragment ? 2)-At which place you are calling setInfo() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

Clear your arraylist before adding the data into it and add before try catch in your code. given like below and notify your adapter.

```
  if(categories!=null){
        categories.clear();
     }

try {
       for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            final String name = object.getString("Name");
            final int Id = object.getInt("ID");
            categories.add(new Category(Id, name));
        }

    }catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, categories);
    rvCategory.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    rvCategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment, tag); instead of fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment, tag);

Difference between **add** and **replace** is:

**replace** removes the existing fragment and adds a new fragment. This means when you press back button the fragment that got replaced will be created with its onCreateView being invoked.

Whereas **add** retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment that means existing fragment will be active and they wont be in 'paused' state hence when a back button is pressed onCreateView is not called for the existing fragment(the fragment which was there before new fragment was added).

In terms of fragment's life cycle events onPause, onResume, onCreateView and other life cycle events will be invoked in case of replace but they wont be invoked in case of add.

Answer (score 0):

Its a common problem faced by most of the android developers and can be solved by following methods.
1. Fist of all, clear the **category** object every time this fragment is loaded/called before adding data to it.
Example. category.clear(); if its a list
2. In your adapter, add this **setHasStableIds(true);** inside the constructor. It will stop duplicating the data in your list.
3. Override following methods in your adapter **(IMP)**

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return category.size();
    }
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: i want to ask one thing more that how i put my main Activity to a cache so that i can't load the api data. only it loads the cache data

Comment: If you don't have large amount of data, then using shared preferences can be a good option. Your data will be stored on cache and can be fetched easily without communicating with server

Comment: i have large amount of data

Comment: In that case, I think you should go with SQLite, because storing large amount of data on shared preferences will not be the best idea(even though its easier).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

First :

if you are using replace then you should use addtobackstack(null) method with it as well. It would not call previous fragment onCreate method again when going back from next fragment to previous fragment. Make sure you are callling API in onCreate Method.

Second :

Try to read about setRetain(True) in fragments, Maybe it'll help you to stop loading fragment oncreate method again. Make sure you are callling API in onCreate Method.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)